# Can someone help figuring out the issue in my hackerrank Frequency Queries code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this problem we are given a 2 dimensional queries like:

```
queries = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2], [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Each query is of the form,

1 x -> insert x

2 y -> remove one occurence of y

3 z -> Check if any integer is present whose frequency is exactly z. If yes, print 1 else 0

For example,

```
Operation   Array   Output
(1,1)       [1]
(2,2)       [1]
(3,2)                   0
(1,1)       [1,1]
(1,1)       [1,1,1]
(2,1)       [1,1]
(3,2)                   1
```

Above example returns an array with the output: [0, 1]

My solution:

```
def freqQuery(queries):
    res = Counter()
    output = []

    for op, value in queries:
        if op == 1:
            res[value] += 1
        elif op == 2:
            if value in res.keys():
                res[value] -= 1
        elif op == 3:
            if value in res.values():
                output.append(1)
            else:
                output.append(0)

    return output
```

Link to the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-queries/problem

It fails the test cases 4/15 with 3 wrong answers and one with exceeding time limit. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

**Update:**

Thank you for the help! My second query was wrong.

New solution:

```
def freqQuery(queries):
    res = Counter()
    output = []

    for op, value in queries:
        if op == 1:
            res[value] += 1
        elif op == 2:
            if res[value] > 0:
                res[value] -= 1
        elif op == 3:
            if value in res.values():
                output.append(1)
            else:
                output.append(0)

    return output
```

Though I am still failing one test case i.e. exceeding time limit. What could I do to improve the efficiency of the code?

Comment: Please add the most relavant parts of the problem to your question, so it can be understood without following an off-site link.

Comment: Edited with detailed description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong answer is obvious. You didn't understand query 3. In query 3, you're asked if there is any key whose count in the dictionary is exactly `z`.

```
        elif op == 2:
            if value in res.keys():
                res[value] -= 1
```

Your code suggests you're blindly decreasing the counter without knowing the actual state.

You are not deleting any keys from the `Counter`.

Think about a simple case, you are asked to add `2` `your_code_state: ({2:1})`, then delete 2 twice `your_code_state: {2:-1}`, then add 2 again  `your_code_state: {2:0}`, check if any `z = 1` exists, for your code, there is none `your_code_state: {2:0}` (as you keep decrementing your counter even if it's negative) but the answer should be 1 `{2:1}`.

So, just check if the counter is negative, if yes don't decrement, stay at 0.

For time improvement, don't do repeated `in` checks, you can keep a separate dictionary/hash map which will store the frequency for each count, for example, if there is a frequency `z`, the second dict will contain `dict2[z] = 1`, else 0. This will bring down all of your operations in the query function to O(1).

```
# Complete the freqQuery function below.
from collections import Counter
def freqQuery(queries):
    d = Counter() # actual values and their count
    f = Counter() # keep the frequency, if f[z] > 0, then we return 1
    output = []
    for command, key in queries:
        if command == 1:
            d[key] += 1 # new value add
            f[d[key]] += 1 # new frequency add
            f[d[key]-1] -= 1 # delete old frequency
        elif command == 2:
            if d[key] > 0:
                d[key] -= 1 # delete
                f[d[key]] += 1 # old frequency increase
                f[d[key]+1] -= 1
        else:
            if f[key] > 0: # O(1)
                output.append(1)
            else:
                output.append(0)
    return output
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue! I have updated the code. But I still don't understand your suggestion to improve the time efficiency.

Comment: check out the code, the logic is simple, each time you add a new value, you also increment the frequency, and decrement old frequency.